# Ajax Function in External File

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I have an ajax call. This script is working fine when I put it in one file with the form that will be loaded with the script.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#uploadbutton").click(function () {
        var referenceNumber = document.getElementById('referenceNumber').value;
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "selectReferenceOrder.php",
            data: 'referenceNumber='+referenceNumber,
            cache: false,
            //data: $('form').serialize(),
            success:function(html)
            {
                document.getElementById('outputReference').innerHTML = html;
                alert('referenceNumber');
            }
        });
    });
});
```

However, when I try to put it in an external file, it doesn't give me anything.

The script of this ajax is functioned as the script that will post the form into the php file.

```
Reference: <input type="text" id="referenceNumber" /> 
<input type="button" id="uploadbutton" value="SEARCH"/>
```

I have tried many ways of doing this, but it still doesn't work:

```
<input type="submit" value="SEARCH" onclick="collectActed()" />

function collectActed () {
    var referenceNumber = document.getElementById('referenceNumber').value;
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "selectReferenceOrder.php",
        data: 'referenceNumber='+referenceNumber,
        cache: false,
        success:function(html) {
            document.getElementById('outputReference').innerHTML = html;
        }
    });
}
```

Please, help.

Comment: How are you loading the external file?

Comment: @sarbbottam I put the script `<script type="text/javascript" src="../actions/ajax.js"></script>` in the head of the file which contains the form, where in the script is the ajax script.

Comment: Can you check the JavaScript console, if there are any error when you load the script?

Comment: I have checked it, it doesn't show anything or any error of javascript.

Comment: Is there any link where I can take a look at it?

Comment: Uh, it will ask you to login first, and i can't give the username and password because this is company project. Is there any option?

Answer (score 0):

Following code works well:

```
<html>
<head>
        <title>Ajax Search</title>
        <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            function searchFor(suchbegriff) {
                var xmlHttp = null;
                // Mozilla, Opera, Safari sowie Internet Explorer 7
                if (typeof XMLHttpRequest != 'undefined') {
                    xmlHttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
                }
                if (!xmlHttp) {
                    // Internet Explorer 6 und älter
                    try {
                        xmlHttp = new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP");
                    } catch (e) {
                        try {
                            xmlHttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
                        } catch (e) {
                            xmlHttp = null;
                        }
                    }
                }
                // If object has been created       
                if (xmlHttp) {
                    var url = "search.php";
                    var params = "search=" + search;

                    xmlHttp.open("POST", url, true);

                    //Headerinformatio for POST request
                    xmlHttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
                    xmlHttp.setRequestHeader("Content-length", params.length);
                    xmlHttp.setRequestHeader("Connection", "close");

                    xmlHttp.onreadystatechange = function () {
                        if (xmlHttp.readyState == 4) {
                            // Zurückgeliefertes Ergebnis wird in den DIV "ergebnis" geschrieben
                            document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = xmlHttp.responseText;
                        }
                    };
                    xmlHttp.send(params);
                }
            }
        </script>
        <script>
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("input").click(function(){
    $("div").load("search.php");
  });
});
</script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <input type="text" onkeyup="searchFor(this.value);"/>
        <div id="search"></div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Sorry for the german comments. I forgot to delete or translate them but I guess you can follow the code

Comment: Can you explain it step by step of the code because it looks a different from what I need. thanks

Comment: In the search.php is the database query handled. var url is used when a xmlhttp-object is created. Each typing on your keyboard fires a request to search.php. It should be possible to replace the search.php with your selectReferenceOrder.php and so one with your upload-button